# Where is a useful comparison of Australian Superannuation schemes?

Tags: investing, australia, superannuation

I'm a New Zealander that has previously worked in Australia long enough to have some superannuation there, but the political agreements that NZ has with Australia don't currently let me take my superannuation money with me now that I've left. I need to choose an Australian superannuation scheme, and I have no knowledge whatsoever of the reputations of the companies that offer superannuation.

I'm looking for information that compares the various Australian superannuation schemes to help me decide. Maybe a website that compares fees, returns, popularity etc? Thanks!

More info for bonus karma:

Ideally, I'd like to choose a socially responsible one (ie "SRI"), but it will still need to have proven performance.

Note that I'm aware NZ and Australia are looking at changing the rules to allow me to bring my money back to NZ's superannuation scheme "Kiwisaver", but I hear rumours that it may give me a tax disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lot of info on different funds, fees, average returns, etc, see [this site](http://www.superratings.com.au/). (Not all sections are free - but areas like Best of the Rest are, and they offer good basic starting info.)

I think for getting further into the nitty-gritty, for example if a fund is socially responsible, you will need to go to the individual fund sites or read reviews - although sites like Morningstar may help. However, a few funds like this are: [HESTA](http://www.hesta.com.au/Members/Investment-Centre/Socially-Responsible-Investing.html), [Cruelty Free Super](http://www.crueltyfreesuper.com.au/), and [VicSuper](http://www.vicsuper.com.au/www/html/7-home-page.asp) (I'm with the latter). It might be useful to check out their sites to orient yourself to the Aussie approach to this issue, and then start searching more broadly from there.

And for what it's worth, for a general overview of the Superannuation system, and some nice-to-know info, see [this page](http://australia.gov.au/topics/economy-money-and-tax/superannuation) on the Oz govt website.

Comment: Thanks gef05, that's exactly the kind of info I was looking for!